# Windows/Cygwin links in R

Tags: windows, r, hyperlink, symlink

[originally posted at [RStudio's support site](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/1055-following-windows-symlinks), but it looks like it's a core R issue, not RStudio.]

I'm trying to figure out how to create a filesystem link that will be traversed within R.  I've tried both Cygwin symlinks & Windows links to no avail.  I'm doing this because I've got a big directory full of large data files that I'd like to avoid copying to my workspace.

To create the symlink, I did `ln -s ../otherdir/data data` in Cygwin. If I then do `ls data/`, I can see the data files through the link.

To create the Windows link, I did a "copy" in Windows Explorer on the `otherdir/data/` directory, then did "paste shortcut" in my workspace and changed the name to `data.lnk`. If I double click that link, I'm taken correctly through the link.

So both links are correctly targeted.

Now in RStudio, I get the following output, indicating that neither link can be traversed:

```
> dir()
[1] "data" "data.lnk" "docs" "src" "tmp"
> dir('data')
character(0)
> dir('data.lnk')
character(0)
> dir('data/')
character(0)
> dir('data.lnk/')
character(0)
```

Is there some variation on this that will work?  I'm using Windows 7 and R 2.13.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Windows shortcut isn't really a filesystem link. It's a regular file, that Explorer knows to treat differently. To other programs, it's just a file.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), a Cygwin symlink is implemented as a shortcut, rather than a true symbolic link, so it will have the same problem.

Have you tried using the `mklink` command to create the link, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)?

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Wow, a third kind of link! =)  Thanks, that worked very well.  I wasn't aware of NTFS links.

Comment: Excellent Works Great!!!! you may need to run the cmd.exe as Administrator for this mklink to work. Right click on All Programs -> Accessories -> Command Prompt and "run as administrator".. and issue the command for example.... mklink /D mysymlink "//targetdir//subdir"     >>>>> This link works from windows explorer and also on cygwin cd ...